# Test whether Android app is available worldwide

Tags: android, google-play

I've got an app in the Android Market that I can see on my phone (US T-Mobile Nexus One), but a user wrote in complaining that he can't see my app on the UK T-Mobile Android Market.

How can I test this?  I've already verified that I've checked "All locations" in my Market publisher console.

Comment: Is your app dependent on version of android? How about screen size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try one of the services like Device Anywhere, which has devices all over the place and might help you sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have't published to the Android Market yet but I remember reading about Market Filters.

The link below will take you to the Market Filters for the Market. At the bottom, in the section titled "Other Filters", there is a bit about other countries. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Is your app copy protected? some builds are not "whitelisted" by the android team as secure enough to host a copy protected app. use Market licensing instead.